# How to convert Normal Map into Diffuse Texture

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map, pbr

[image]

So I have this top hat 3D model that I've made, but for some reason when I try to convert the Normal Map into a Diffuse texture, there is one specific part that is problematic.[image: Problematic part]

Here is a picture of the normals:
[image: Crumpled Paper Normals]

I am trying to turn this **crumpled paper normals** into something like a **black and white** base color **texture** and then mix with other textures that are supposed to be on this 3D model.
[image]
I have gone to trying such convoluted node setups because I want to **PBR bake the Normal Map WITH the other base color textures that I have (but aren't connected right now)**

I'd be glad If I could just plug in the Normal Map in the Principled BSDF and bake it **ALL in ONE COMBINED diffuse texture like the way it is shown in the Material Preview, for example (because the NORMAL map is shown with that option),** but when I PBR bake, the roughness and base color come out, **but not the normal map...** *But is it possible?* I can't have the normals separated from the diffuse texture, because the engine I am trying to import it in supports **ONLY one image texture.**

Here's the .blend file: [image]

Also - I have baked on Cycles, BUT it doesn't quite match the expected result (mainly due to lighting)